# How do I Create a 'Layered' Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2015 Plug-In

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to generate a 'layered' Crystal Report using the Crystal Report plugin for Visual Studio 2015.  I am having formatting problems and would like suggestions on grouping or formatting that will help me achieve something like the below image (what I am trying to achieve).

The first layer includes headers--the row beginning with Time of Search.  There are multiple results for that section.  I.e. Time of Search could have that 11/12 value pictured and an 11/14, 11/19...

The second layer returns a list of details associated with the first result.  In fact, for this example there would be 187 results.  My difficulty is that this second section has its own header as well.  After printing the seconds sections details, I would like the first header to be displayed, followed by the first header's data, then second header, then second headers data.

There is no way I can know prior to generating the report how many section ones will be needed.  Additionally, I do not know how many section twos will be associated with the given sections one.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was achieved by using  two groups and placing the Time of Search row in one group header say 1A.  The details from that row were placed in group header 1B.

A second group say 2 contained the blue box row as its header.  The list below was filled within the details area.